# Angular - How to use a custom component inside a MatDialogRef Material Dialog?

Tags: angular

I have a module+component called `List`, which in turn displays a list of `Item` components (`<my-item></my-item>`). That works fine. HOWEVER, I cannot seem to use `<my-item></my-item>` in a Dialog opened from the `List` component.

The following fails with the error `Template parse errors: 'my-item' is not a known element`:

`list.component.ts:`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { MatDialog, MatAccordionDisplayMode } from '@angular/material'

import { ItemDialogComponent } from '../../../../core/components/item-dialog/item-dialog.component'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './interview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./interview.component.scss'],
  providers: [],
})
export class ListComponent {
  showItemDialog = (item) => {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(ItemDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        item,
      },
    })
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {})
  }
}
```

`list.component.html`:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item in items">
          <button (click)="showItemDialog(item)">View Item</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`item-dialog.component.html`:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <my-item [item]="item"></my-item>
</div>
```

I imagine I just need to import `ItemComponent` in the correct way, or need to pass it to the `MatDialog` somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Here are the modules:

`item.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'

import { SharedModule } from '../../modules/shared.module'

import { ItemComponent } from './item.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ItemComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule],
  exports: [SharedModule, ItemComponent],
})
export class ItemModule {}
```

`item-dialog.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'

import { SharedModule } from '../../modules/shared.module'
import { ItemModule } from '../item/item.module'

import { ItemDialogComponent } from './item-dialog.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ItemDialogComponent, Item],
  imports: [SharedModule],
  exports: [SharedModule, ItemDialogComponent, Item],
})
export class ItemDialogModule {}
```

Comment: What is `Item` in `import { Item } from '../item/item.module` ? `ItemComponent` should be declared in `ItemModule`, and `ItemModule` should be imported in `ItemDialogModule`.

Comment: Right you are. That was a typo in what I pasted - wasn’t actually in my code.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the `ItemModule` in your `ItemDialogModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'

import { SharedModule } from '../../modules/shared.module'
import { ItemModule } from '../item/item.module'

import { ItemDialogComponent } from './item-dialog.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ItemDialogComponent], <== No need to redeclare Item
  imports: [SharedModule, ItemModule], //<== Import the module here
  exports: [SharedModule, ItemDialogComponent],
})
export class ItemDialogModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably didnt include your `item` component in either

1. Module you are declaring it with `declares` end/or `exports` sections of module definition
2. You didn't include your module in `imports` of using module definition